# set width:100% in css only when it exceeds the table cell

Tags: css, width

I have this html page that contains a table with 3 columns and a row.

```
<html><head>    
<title>Test input text in table</title>
<style type="text/css">      
table {width:500px; border-top: 1px solid #ff0000; border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;}
table td {border-right: 1px solid #00ff00; border-bottom: 1px solid #00ff00;}
#selectbox {        
width : 100%;       
} 
</style>    
</head><body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><p>column one</p></td>
<td><p>column two</p></td>
<td><p>column three</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
<td style="width:300px">Dymamic Text : <select id="selectbox"><option value="1">Small Content1</option>
<option value="2">Small Content2</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

I have a dropdown in 3rd cell. Dropdown width is 100% by default. I gave width:100% just because parent cell should not expand with dropdown content.

The problem that I am facing is, the dropdown shows in 100% even when dropdown has less content or no content as well. How do I make sure the dropdown gets 100% width only when it has large content(or the content exceeds table cell)?

Comment: You can try 'width:auto'

Comment: with "width:auto;" container cell(td) expands when you have large texts in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#selectbox {        
   width : 50%;//or try 'auto'
   max-width : 100%;
}
```